# tracing a sql server stored procedure not appearing in profiler

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying to trace the execution of a sql server stored procedure that gets executed from within a large java application. I first changed the stored procedure to complete the task I needed to do and I tested within sql server and it worked fine, with all triggers working too. However, when I apply the changes and run the code it seems like the changed stored procedure is not executed but just the original version. I tried to use profile to trace the execution but the weird thing is that it does not appear. Again testing the inserts manually does then show the procedure in profiler.

I tried to trace the code that implements this procedure, found it and wrote some trace comments to tag the execution but again the class trace commenting does not occur. As if the class does not get called. I have added the procedure just in case someone sees a fault but like I said it works fine testing in SQL server.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @KeepStoreLingerTime int
DECLARE @KeepDeleteLingerTime int
DECLARE @StoreActionID int
DECLARE @insertedID int;

IF @TimeToExecute IS NULL
BEGIN
   SELECT @KeepStoreLingerTime = [Value] FROM SystemProperty WHERE [Name] = 'KeepStoreLingerTimeInMinutes'
   SELECT @KeepDeleteLingerTime = [Value] FROM SystemProperty WHERE [Name] = 'KeepDeleteLingerTimeInMinutes'
   IF (@KeepDeleteLingerTime >= @KeepStoreLingerTime) SET @KeepStoreLingerTime = @KeepDeleteLingerTime+1
   SET @TimeToExecute = dateadd(mi, @KeepStoreLingerTime, getutcdate())
END

SELECT @StoreActionID = [ID] FROM StoreActionQueue 
  WHERE Parameter=@Parameter AND StorageRuleID=@StorageRuleID AND StoreFlags=@StoreFlags
  IF @StoreActionID IS NOT NULL AND @StoreFlags != 11
BEGIN
  UPDATE StoreActionQueue SET FilterID = @FilterID WHERE [ID] = @StoreActionID
 END
ELSE
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO StoreActionQueue (TimeToExecute, Operation, Parameter, StorageRuleID, FilterID, StoreFlags)
     SELECT @TimeToExecute, @Operation, @Parameter, @StorageRuleID, @FilterID, @StoreFlags FROM Call WHERE [ID]=@Parameter AND Active=0
             AND (OnlineCount>0 OR OnlineScreenCount>0 OR (Flags&POWER(2,26)=POWER(2,26))) --bit26 indicates META-DATA-ONLY

   ---- INSERT if a row is successfully inserted

   IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
    IF @StoreFlags = 11
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO StoreActionQueue (TimeToExecute, Operation, Parameter, 
          StorageRuleID, FilterID, StoreFlags)
        SELECT DATEADD(mi, 2, GETUTCDATE()), @Operation, @Parameter, 
           @StorageRuleID, @FilterID, 9 FROM Call 
        WHERE [ID]=@Parameter AND Active=0
    END
   END
  END
```

Is there a way to log anything from lets say within the procedure to a file? In java (eclipse) other than looking at call hierarchy etc. is there a suggestion on how to match where the class gets called.

```
public class ProcessingController extends TimeController implements
    TimeObserver {
```

Comment: Which events were you tracing in Profiler?

Comment: stored procedures [ALL]  & TSQL [SQL:StmtStarting, SQL:StmtCompleted and filtered columns on table name

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood you somewhere, it sounds like the issue is in the java class.  I'm afraid that that's outside my particular bailiwick.